# FormData() not working as expected - Laravel/Vue file upload

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a multiple file upload with VueJS & Laravel.

I'm running into an issue where, when using `FormData()` and adding a file, 2 spaces gets used up.

Consider the following VueJS method

```
uploadFiles: function(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    this.inputs.forEach((input, index) => {
        formData.append('uploads[1][]', 'something big')
        formData.append('uploads[1][]', 'something else');

        formData.append('uploads[2][]', input.file);
        formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 1')
        formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 2')
        formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 3');
        formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 4');
    });
    const headers = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}
    axios.post( '/upload-multiple',formData,headers)
    .then(function(){
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
    })
    .catch(function(){
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
    });
},
```

The Laravel method receiving the request

```
public function multiple(Request $request)
{
  dd($request->all());
}
```

When I run the AJAX request, this is what I get in response

```
array:1 [
  "uploads" => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "something big"
      1 => "something else"
    ]
    2 => array:5 [
      0 => "null"
      1 => "something 1"
      2 => "something 2"
      3 => "something 3"
      4 => "something 4"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And thats exactly what I expected, the first value in the second array being null given that I never selected a file yet.

However, if I now select an file and submit the request, this is what I get back

```
array:1 [
  "uploads" => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "something big"
      1 => "something else"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      0 => UploadedFile {#457
        -test: false
        -originalName: "30_flash_sale_desktop.jpg"
        -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
        -error: 0
        #hashName: null
        path: "/tmp"
        filename: "php15pIms"
        basename: "php15pIms"
        pathname: "/tmp/php15pIms"
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/tmp/php15pIms"
        aTime: 2019-12-10 10:21:02
        mTime: 2019-12-10 10:21:02
        cTime: 2019-12-10 10:21:02
        inode: 265696
        size: 334749
        perms: 0100600
        owner: 1000
        group: 1000
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
      1 => "something 2"
      2 => "something 3"
      3 => "something 4"
    ]
  ]
]
```

If you look closely, you'll notice `"something 1"` has disappeared.

Reordering the `formData.append()'s` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Why does adding a file always make the first appended text disappear?

**Update**
Here's a screenshot of the payload (after reordering to see if it made a difference)

[image: Payload sent]

**Update 2**

I've found a work-around solution, but it doesn't explain what causes the actual problem in the first place. If I hard code the keys then all data comes through as expected.

```
formData.append('uploads[2][0]', input.file);
formData.append('uploads[2][1]', 'something 1')
formData.append('uploads[2][2]', 'something 2')
formData.append('uploads[2][3]', 'something 3');
formData.append('uploads[2][4]', 'something 4');
```

Interestingly though, when look at the response, the file object is 5th in position despite being place at position `[0]`.

```
array:1 [
  "uploads" => array:1 [
    2 => array:5 [
      1 => "something 1"
      2 => "something 2"
      3 => "something 3"
      4 => "something 4"
      0 => UploadedFile {#457
        -test: false
        -originalName: "Screenshot 2019-12-10 at 12.20.07.png"
        -mimeType: "image/png"
        -error: 0
        #hashName: null
        path: "/tmp"
        filename: "phpTkwuKI"
        basename: "phpTkwuKI"
        pathname: "/tmp/phpTkwuKI"
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/tmp/phpTkwuKI"
        aTime: 2019-12-11 09:47:05
        mTime: 2019-12-11 09:47:05
        cTime: 2019-12-11 09:47:05
        inode: 265716
        size: 92571
        perms: 0100600
        owner: 1000
        group: 1000
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

**Update 3**

I can only presume this is a problem with Laravel's `Request` class as other people have been able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: You are missing `;` after `formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 1')` & `formData.append('uploads[2][]', 'something 2')`. I dont know if this would have something to do with it?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks Patrick, I added the semicolons however this made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get `console.log('SUCCESS!!');` when doing the `POST`?

Comment: Yes, the requires fires successfully, it's just somehow adding a file seems to take up one space and overwrite something else in the process.

Comment: I know this isnt the solution, in case where you want multiple uploads of images, but what if you have that one field as the last of the array? Does the array then close correctly on POST?

Comment: If I move the `something 1` to be the last appended data, and have the file as the first thing like shown above in my question, then `"something 1"` appears at the bottom of the array, however `"something 2"` disappears. Really strange issue.

Comment: But if you move the `formData.append('uploads[2][]', input.file);` to the end, then what happens?

Comment: It makes no difference. I had tried this in the beginning, as mention in my post along with the screenshot

Comment: But if you have `formData.append('uploads[2][]', input.file);` at the end, then it cant delete anything that comes after.

Comment: You would think so, but it doesn't make a difference.